# How to enable column indicator in Qt Creator?

Tags: qt-creator

Visual Assist X has a nice feature for Visual Studio called [column indicator](http://www.wholetomato.com/products/features/column.asp). It displays a vertical line in text editor on the specified column(I use 80th column). This heps you not to write a very long horizontal statements

Is it possible to enable such a feature in Qt Creator? How is it called and how to enable it?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. See Tools / Options / Text Editor / Display / Text Wrapping / **Display right margin at column:**.